# JQuery: Function called by Matching classes not working when wrapped with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, animation

So I'm trying to clone html-content form one div to another, and I've gotten it to work nice, but I want a fade-in/fade-out effect on it (using animate 'opacity', since fadeOut messed up the HTML), however when wrapped in the animation-function my `.html():` doesn't work properly.
Here's my code:

JS:

WORKING:

```
function cloneContent($projectItem) {
                $lightbox = jQuery('.lightbox');    

                $LBChild = $lightBox.find('*'); //any child


                $LBChild.each( function(i, e) {

                    $LBclone = jQuery('.LB-clone'); //item to clone

                    _LBclasses = this.classList;

                    for(var i=0,len=_LBclasses.length; i<len; i++) {
                        if ($LBclone.hasClass(_LBclasses[i])) {

                            $LBmatch = jQuery(this);
                            $clonePair = $projectItem.parents('.gallery-item').find('.LB-clone.' + _LBclasses[i]);
                            $clonePairHtml = $clonePair.html();
                            $LBmatch.html($clonePairHtml);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } //close cloneContent
```

NOT WORKING:

```
function cloneContent($projectItem) {
                $lightbox = jQuery('.lightbox');    

                $LBChild = $lightBox.find('*'); //any child


                $LBChild.each( function(i, e) {

                    $LBclone = jQuery('.LB-clone'); //item to clone

                    _LBclasses = this.classList;

                    for(var i=0,len=_LBclasses.length; i<len; i++) {
                        if ($LBclone.hasClass(_LBclasses[i])) {

                            $LBmatch = jQuery(this);
                            $clonePair = $projectItem.parents('.gallery-item').find('.LB-clone.' + _LBclasses[i]);
                            $clonePairHtml = $clonePair.html();

//When function is wrapped in animation, id doesn't work!
                                $LBmatch.animate({opacity: 0 },250, function() {
                                    $LBmatch.html($clonePairHtml);
                                }).animate({opacity : 1}, 500); 
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } //close cloneContent
```

Here's a fiddle with some alerts that clarifies the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/popmouth/sg5sq72e/15/

Comment: Try it like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/Lvxo9xax/

Comment: Thanks I was a bit unclear with what wasn't working ... I'll update my question.

Comment: Oh, I see it. This is a duplicate of [closure inside loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), and note that all your variables are **global**

Comment: Ok, so I need to make each match into a local variable?

Comment: It needs to be more like -> https://jsfiddle.net/7sk4dyx5/

Comment: Thanks mate! I actually never realised that putting "var" infront made a difference, but this makes it local right, preventing overrides?

Comment: Yes, the dollarsign does nothing in javascript variables, they should be declared with `var`, `let` or `const` to be local.

Answer (score 0):

I think you doing it wrong you have to animate into callback 
         function not after

```
$LBmatch.animate({opacity: 0 },250, function() {                       
         $LBmatch.html($clonePairHtml).animate({opacity : 1}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Ok, your're probably right, but why is this better?

Comment: this is better because after first animation complete you have to apply your second animation.you also can done it below,$LBmatch.animate({opacity: 0 },250,complete:function() {

            $LBmatch.html($clonePairHtml).animate({opacity : 1}, 500);         
            
         });